# Writing out an Alternating Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I am trying to write out what is in $A_4$ and $A_6$, their general form, not the whole $n!/2$ cause that would be a lot. My main question is how do I do that. I know they are all the even permutations from their symmetric groups respectively.  I also know the identity is in each one of them.

Would this be it?

$A_4$: e, (abc), (ab)(cd)?

$A_6$: e, (abc), (abcde), (ab)(cd), (abcd)(ef), (abc)(def)?

Is this the write way to write it out?

Edit 1: If this is it, then why would I be asked to write $A_4$ as 8 three-cycles and 3 two-cycles?

Comment: That's fine. You need all possibilities with an even number of evenölength cycles and found them all

Comment: So it is that simple.

Comment: They just asked you to *actually list* all elements of $A_4$. $A_4$ has $12$ elements, one being the identity, $8$ elements of order $3$ ($(abc),\dots$) and $3$ elements of order $2$ ($(ab)(cd),\dots$).

Comment: but didnt I just do it? or would I have to go in and move about the stuff?